# How to pass ArrayList<Class> from one activity to another?

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist

I have this `ArrayList<ToLet> toLet;`

The ToLet class is a POJO class.

Now how can I pass this from one activity to another? What is the best way to do it?

I have gone through the following links..

[How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

[How to pass ArrayList<Custom_Object> from one activity to another in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637625/how-to-pass-arraylistcustom-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

but did not help me.So If anyone knows the answer,let me know

Comment: Why did it not help you?

Comment: I am not getting how to implement it?

Comment: You should re-read those two posts you linked.  Lots of good answers there.

Comment: Just refer this. It exactly shows what you need.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830894/passing-arraylist-between-activities

Comment: @ling.s so you me to say i need to make my ToLet implement parcelable?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this for passing ArrayList tolet; one activity to Another activity.

Create the object of your class :-

```
ToLet obj = new ToLet();

ArrayList<ToLet> tolet;
int size = tolet.getSize();    
Intent ii = new Intent(your_current_class.this, next_class_where_you_want_to_use);
ii.putExtra("listsize",size);

 startActivity(ii);
```

Now Go to your next class and use :-

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String mylistsize = intent.getIntExtra("listsize",default value);
```

and AndroidMainest.xml file update this activity.

```
<activity android:name="yourcurrentclass" />
<activity android:name="yournextclass" />
```

It should solve your query.

Comment: No i need to pass the object only since i need to get the size of the arraylist in the next class

Comment: it will get the arrayList size and pass to your another activity.

Comment: No now i will only get the size what about the object?

Comment: there is many solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819238/help-with-passing-arraylist-and-parcelable-activity  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433834/android-how-to-pass-arraylistobject-from-an-activity-to-another  there is your query . check and try to use.

Comment: Bad Parcelable exception is the one which i am getting ? why does it give me ?

Comment: plz change this line public static final Parcelable.Creator<Persona> creator = new Creator<Persona>() { to public static final Parcelable.Creator<Persona> CREATOR = new Creator<Persona>() {  creator should be capital . and follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348627/bad-parcelable-exception  it should solve

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24551/discussion-between-goofy-and-rahul-rawat)

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating an object of intent, you can take advantage of following two methods 
for passing objects between two activities.

[putParceble](http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/10/28/writing-parcelable-classes-for-android/)

[putSerializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29)

The following tell you about putParceble

Review *[Writing Parcelable classes for Android](http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/10/28/writing-parcelable-classes-for-android/)* carefully. Here they are using Hashmap to store the values and pass the object to another class.

### OR

---

Make one class, `ObjectA`. In that, I used all the setter and getter methods.

```
package com.ParcableExample.org;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

/**
 * A basic object that can be parcelled to
 * transfer between objects.
 */

public class ObjectA implements Parcelable
{
    private String strValue = null;
    private int intValue = 0;

    /**
     * Standard basic constructor for non-parcel
     * object creation.
     */

    public ObjectA()
    {
    }

    /**
     *
     * Constructor to use when re-constructing object
     * from a parcel.
     *
     * @param in a parcel from which to read this object.
     */

    public ObjectA(Parcel in)
    {
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    /**
     * Standard getter
     *
     * @return strValue
     */
    public String getStrValue()
    {
        return this.strValue;
    }

    /**
     * Standard setter
     *
     * @param strValue
     */

    public void setStrValue(String strValue)
    {
        this.strValue = strValue;
    }


    /**
     * Standard getter
     *
     * @return intValue
     */
    public Integer getIntValue()
    {
        return this.intValue;
    }

    /**
     * Standard setter
     *
     * @param strValue
     */
    public void setIntValue(Integer intValue)
    {
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        // We just need to write each field into the
        // parcel. When we read from parcel, they
        // will come back in the same order

        dest.writeString(this.strValue);
        dest.writeInt(this.intValue);
    }

    /**
     *
     * Called from the constructor to create this
     * object from a parcel.
     *
     * @param in parcel from which to re-create object.
     */
    public void readFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {
        // We just need to read back each
        // field in the order that it was
        // written to the parcel

        this.strValue = in.readString();
        this.intValue = in.readInt();
    }

    /**
    *
    * This field is needed for Android to be able to
    * create new objects, individually or as arrays.
    *
    * This also means that you can use use the default
    * constructor to create the object and use another
    * method to hyrdate it as necessary.
    */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator()
    {
        @Override
        public ObjectA createFromParcel(Parcel in)
        {
            return new ObjectA(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Object[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new ObjectA[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Then make one Activity that is used to send the Object to another activity.

```
package com.ParcableExample.org;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ParcableExample extends Activity
{
    private Button btnClick;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initControls();
    }

    private void initControls()
    {
        btnClick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                ObjectA obj = new ObjectA();
                obj.setIntValue(1);
                obj.setStrValue("Chirag");

                Intent i = new Intent(ParcableExample.this,MyActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("com.package.ObjectA", obj);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now finally make one another activity that read the Object and get the value from that.

```
package com.ParcableExample.org;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        ObjectA obj = bundle.getParcelable("com.package.ObjectA");

        Log.i("---------- Id   ",":: "+obj.getIntValue());
        Log.i("---------- Name ",":: "+obj.getStrValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not just an object its ArrayList<ToLet> toLet; and the ToLet class is POJO? now?

Comment: You can pass ArrayList as a object to another activity.Try it by the same method \

Comment: can you please help on that

Comment: hey i get this Bad Parcelable exception is the one which i am getting ? why does it give me ?

Comment: In the above example you have on string and int which your are reading and writing i have on list? how to read and write that?

Comment: watch  closely you will get

Comment: No i  am getting can you help